# How do I know which docker frontend (syntax) version is used

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy---link has a text that says:

> Added in `docker/dockerfile:1.4`

This refers to https://docs.docker.com/build/dockerfile/frontend/. An example of its usage:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:4

FROM alpine
COPY --link /foo /bar
```

But how do I know which current version of frontend is used if I do not specify the syntax specifically?